# How to set up automatic payments for 3DS cards using Stripe

Tags: node.js, cron, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

I'm developing an app, and I included a payment module. Let's say the balance is 10 and Assume that if a user configures auto charge, 5 additional will be added automatically if the balance is less than 5. After that, I use cron to automatically charge the amount every four hours. The problem is that this flow doesn't function with 3DS cards. Is there a way to put this into practice so the user doesn't have to visit that extra page in order to finish the transaction? There is no set amount to be charged; it can be any price depending on what the user enters, and there is no set number of times per day the user will be charged.

I tried a temporary workaround to send an email and display a banner with a complete transaction button that will take the user to the 3ds page to finish the transaction. The purchase has been initiated, but it is not automatically charged. I need the flow to continue without this additional step.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.